# Automating Data Download from S&P GSCI Website

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, web

I have a "dataset.xlsx" file containing information on various S&P GSCI commodities. I downloaded this data manually from the S&P GSCI webpage, and now I want to automate the process to keep my dataset up to date.

For example, consider this S&P GSCI Precious Metals page: https://www.spglobal.com/spdji/en/indices/commodities/sp-gsci-precious-metals/#overview.

Here are the steps I'd like to automate:

- Click on the "Export" link to download the data.
- Repeat the process for all the S&P indices in my dataset (e.g., Energy, Metals, Industrial Metals, etc.).

I've noticed that the "Export" link seems to be connected to the plot on the page, and selecting different time frames on the plot changes the data available for export.

I'm currently using Python, and I believe web scraping could be a solution, but I'm not sure how to proceed, especially when dealing with dynamic content. Can anyone provide guidance or code examples on how to achieve this?

Thank you!